# Where does the Terminator get scissors and a box cutter from?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

Scene inside the hotel where he calibrates his forearm and cuts out his eye to expose the Terminator eye sensor.

Where did he get these tools from?

Answer (score 3):

The Terminator stole the tools and equipment from a hardware store between the time he landed and the time he booked the hotel room. This also explains where the money needed for the room came from.

> He cruised Los Feliz Boulevard until it knifed into Sunset, then
> turned southeast. A few blocks later, he found what he was looking
> for. A hardware-store owner just opening up for the day
>
> Terminator was his first customer. And his last.
>
> Afterward, on his way to secure weapons, he located his base of
> operations, renting a room at the Panama.
>
> He looked down at the tools he had raided as they lay on the bed.
>
> **X-Acto blades. Tweezers. Pliers. Penlight. Metric set. Screwdrivers.
> Several files.** And other odds and ends. He had also taken a pile of
> work clothes and the owner’s black leather jacket as backups to the
> clothes he had on. There wasn’t much money in the register, but then,
> Terminator didn’t need much. This would be a short mission.
>
> <sub><sup>[Terminator: Official Novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel))</sup></sub>